# Registration Form that Submits to Database and Sends a Confirmation Email to the User with Their Info - 2 Actions, 1 Button

Tags: php, forms

I thought the solution would be easy to find, but I cannot find it. I want my registration form to submit to the database and send the form data to the user's email, as a confirmation email, at the same time and using the same submit button. It seems logical that the form would have two actions, but I'm finding no example of such a thing. Perhaps some PHP code on the registration page that will recognize the successful submission and send the data to a php file that will process an email at the same time the data is being inserted into the database table??

register.php, the PHP above the HTML

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['usr_id']) && empty($_SESSION['usr_id']) ) {
} else {
   header('Location: mustlogout.php'); #redirect URL
}
?>

<?php

include_once 'db.php';

//set validation error flag as false
$error = false;

//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
    $user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user_name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);

$name = stripslashes($name);
$user_name = stripslashes($user_name);
$email = stripslashes($email);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$cpassword = stripslashes($cpassword);

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) {    /* name can contain only alpha characters and space */
        $error = true;
        $name_error = "Name must contain only letters";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-0-9 ]+$/",$user_name)) {    /* letters and numbers */
        $error = true;
        $user_name_error = "User name can contain only letters and numbers";
    }
    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {    /* will accept only email addresses */
        $error = true;
        $email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
    }
    if(strlen($password) <6 ) {    /* must be 6 or more characters */
        $error = true;
        $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
    }
    if($password != $cpassword) {    /* must match the first password entry */
        $error = true;
        $cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
    }
    if (!$error) {
        if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO forumusers(name,user_name,email,password) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $user_name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . md5($password) . "')")) {
            $successmsg = "Successfully Registered! <a href='login.php'>Click here to Login</a>";    /* if register is successful */
        } else {
            $errormsg = "Error in registering...Please try again later!";    /* if register is not successful */
        }
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/index.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
```

register.php, the form in the HTML

```
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegion3" -->
<div class="title-bar"><n6>Forum Registration</n6></div> 
    <div class="main-content">
<div class="form-reg" style="margin-bottom: 4em;"><!-- Begin div to contain form -->
            <table width="50%" style="padding-left: 20px;">

<form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="signupform">
    <fieldset>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <label for="name" class="formfield-names">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name" required value="<?php if($error) echo $name; ?>" class="form-control" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($name_error)) echo $name_error; ?></span>
        </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
        <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <label for="name" class="formfield-names">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_name" minlength="5" maxlength="15" placeholder="5 to 15 Letters/Numbers" required value="<?php if($error) echo $user_name; ?>" class="form-control" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($user_name_error)) echo $user_name_error; ?></span>
        </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>   
        <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <label for="name" class="formfield-names">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter a Valid Email" required value="<?php if($error) echo $email; ?>" class="form-control" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($email_error)) echo $email_error; ?></span>
        </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <label for="name" class="formfield-names">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" minlength="6" maxlength="16" placeholder="6 to 16 Chracters" required class="form-control" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($password_error)) echo $password_error; ?></span>
        </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <label for="name" class="formfield-names">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required class="form-control" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($cpassword_error)) echo $cpassword_error; ?></span>
        </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
        <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Register" class="button" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td><div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;" class="formfield-names">Already Registered? <a href="login.php">Login Here</a></div></td></tr>
</table>
<span class="formfield-names"><?php if (isset($successmsg)) { echo $successmsg; } ?></span>
<span class="formfield-names"><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg; } ?></span>

</div><!-- End div to contain form -->
</div>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
```

I found alot of "form with two buttons" and various "how to submit a form to a database" and "how to send email with a form" and displaying various confirmation messages and the one I found with the 2 actions appears to be incomplete. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you not send the email from the same script that registration is processed in?

Comment: Just add a email-send when the insert is successful? It's not really rocket-science? Right under the `$successmsg`-variable, add a `mail(//info goes here)`

Comment: Come on! Just send the email after you have confirmed that the database query is successful. It's not a big deal, and you don't need a second action. You can do multiple things in a single php file

Comment: **Danger**: `stripslashes` reverses the effect of `mysqli_real_escape_string`. You are vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite a simple question, you should try thinking out the process before coding it.

```
some code ....

        if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO forumusers(name,user_name,email,password) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $user_name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . md5($password) . "')")) {
            $successmsg = "Successfully Registered! <a href='login.php'>Click here to Login</a>";    /* if register is successful */

// add email here.

        }

some code ....
```

Answer (score 0):

> It seems logical that the form would have two actions

No. The `action` attribute determines the URL to which the data will be sent. HTML is not designed to send data to multiple places (because it is geared up to display one page at a time).

If you want to do more than one thing with the data, you just need to make the program at that URL do more than one thing.

Your existing PHP already does two things:

- Inserts data into a database
- Outputs an HTML page back to the browser

You just need to insert the code to send the email into the same program.

---

> Perhaps some PHP code on the registration page that will recognize the successful submission and send the data to a php file that will process an email at the same time the data is being inserted into the database table

If you want to divide your code up into smaller, logically grouped, chunks: You can use includes, functions and classes.